# Determine APs wireless regulatory domain

Tags: wireless

The problem that I have observed intermittently as kernel patches come through, is that my wifi does not always obtain the regulatory domain from the AP.  The symptom is poor connectivity with frequent drops, and the work-aroud has been to issue the command `sudo iw reg set US`, which I usually place in /etc/rc.local as `iw reg set US`

So the question is: does anyone know how to query the AP (a linksys WRT610N) to ask what regulatory domain it is set to?

An excerpt from /var/log/dmesg from my last boot follows, after changing /etc/default/crda as recommended in comments below:  *If* I am reading this correctly, the regulatory domain is initialized to world, and then using the information in /etc/default/crda, the regulatory domain is updated to become US.

```
[   12.109314] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   12.109317] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   12.109318] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   12.109320] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
[   12.109419] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[   12.124492] intel_rapl: domain uncore energy ctr 380974:380974 not working, skip
[   12.183857] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   12.394864] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   12.394867] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   12.394868] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   12.394869] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   12.394870] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   12.394871] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   12.394872] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   12.522154] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[   12.523937] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[   12.523939] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   12.523941] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[   12.523942] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[   12.523943] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   12.523943] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   12.523944] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   12.523945] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[   12.523946] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
```

Comment: Amending rc.local is probably the less good alternative. I suggest you amend /etc/default/crda and make the last line: REGDOMAIN=US Thanks.

Comment: @chili555  Thanks - it certainly does happen earlier in the boot process.  I still seem to be getting set to the world domain first, and then resetting to US, however I assume that this becomes system wide now.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant lines from dmesg? If they are lengthy, then here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give us the link.

Comment: @chili555 I have updated the question with the relevant lines

Comment: Since it is less than a half-second before the update to US and since, I assume, you connect on boot without drama, I don't think I'd worry about it. As for the CRDA setting in the router, I'm afraid I haven't any suggestions. It is not manipulable any way I can see in my Linksys. I wonder if it's burned into the silicon during manufacture depending on where it is expected to be sold.

Comment: Usually connect on boot, sometimes it just doesn't take.  I believe the CRDA is firmware on the AP - there's no downloads for firmware upgrade.  I suppose Cisco thinks they did it right, so there's no need.  It's not a functional problem at this time, but a puzzle waiting to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does anyone know how to query the AP (a linksys WRT610N) to ask what regulatory domain it is set to?

The short answer is: You can't query the AP for their regulatory domain.

> An excerpt from /var/log/dmesg from my last boot follows, after changing /etc/default/crda as recommended in comments below: If I am reading this correctly, the regulatory domain is initialized to world, and then using the information in /etc/default/crda, the regulatory domain is updated to become US.

That's how it's [supposed to work](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory/processing_rules#Wireless_core_initialization):

> Upon the initialization of the wireless core (cfg80211) a world regulatory domain (highly restrictive) will be set as the central regulatory domain. **If CRDA is present the latest dynamic world regulatory domain is queried from CRDA**; if it is not then a statically defined list is used.

I wouldn't worry about it, if your 802.11 device is working as it should and there isn't other problems, you can ignore it.

Comment: This is not correct. [802.11d](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11d-2001) provides a capability for APs to announce country and regulatory details, and indeed most APs do so.

Comment: @Dan "As of January 1, 2015, the U.S. Federal Communications Commission ruled that new devices are not allowed to rely solely on 802.11d for setting country-specific radio parameters" most devices are set with the US parameters in mind. So basically, unless you have a very specialized device (like a PtP radio station) most consumer wifi (like my access point) just set the most restrictive restrictions and rolls with it (which saves them implementing 802.11d at all).

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that ruling. However the question, as worded, is about _whether it's possible to determine an AP's regulatory info_… not whether most devices or OSes **use** the AP's regulatory info, or whether it's legal for them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> So the question is: does anyone know how to query the AP (a linksys WRT610N) to > ask what regulatory domain it is set to?

Linux's standard [`iw` tool](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw) for WiFi configuration does this.

[802.11d](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11d-2001), dating to 2001, provides a capability for WiFi access points to announce country and regulatory details, and indeed most access points do so. See the ["802.11 Framing in Detail" chapter of *802.11 Wireless Networks: The Definitive Guide*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/80211-wireless-networks/0596100523/ch04.html) for details of exactly how this information is encoded in WiFi frames.

Here's an excerpt from a WiFi scan I just did:

```
$ sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
BSS aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff(on wlan0)
        ...
        Information elements from Probe Response frame:
                ...
                Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 
                DS Parameter set: channel 1
                TIM: DTIM Count 0 DTIM Period 1 Bitmap Control 0x0 Bitmap[0] 0x0
                Country: US     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
                        Channels [1 - 11] @ 30 dBm
                ERP: <no flags>
                Extended supported rates: 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0 

BSS 00:11:22:33:44:55(on wlan0)
        ...
        Information elements from Probe Response frame:
                Country: US     Environment: bogus
                        Channels [36 - 36] @ 30 dBm
                        Channels [40 - 40] @ 30 dBm
                        ...
                        Channels [52 - 52] @ 24 dBm
                        ...
                        Channels [149 - 149] @ 30 dBm
                        ...

BSS f0:0f:ba:ba:12:34(on wlan0)
        ...
        Information elements from Probe Response frame:
                ...
                Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 6.0 9.0 12.0 18.0 
                DS Parameter set: channel 11
                TIM: DTIM Count 0 DTIM Period 1 Bitmap Control 0x0 Bitmap[0] 0x0
                Country: CA     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
                        Channels [1 - 12] @ 30 dBm
```

The third AP shown here is one where I've changed the country code setting to Canada (rather than USA), to demonstrate the possibility of varying this field.

**Despite all this**, it appears that neither mainstream Linux (nor most other OSes, as far as I can tell) actually pay any attention to the 802.11d settings of the APs that they connect to, probably because it's possible for APs to give misconfigured/outdated/conflicting information. The USA's FCC [has ruled that devices must not rely exclusively on APs' regulatory configuration to set their own regulatory configuration](https://apps.fcc.gov/kdb/GetAttachment.html?id=5NjjaXsjV97%2BhlMWvZ1QRw%3D%3D&desc=594280%20D01%20Configuration%20Control%20v02r01&tracking_number=39498); in practice, this means that most devices simply *ignore* APs' regulatory information and use their own, which tends to be set restrictively by default.